# MS ACCESS how to change a query criteria to look up a record and then create a report

Tags: ms-access, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvPRN.png)i have a program that create field tickets, when the ticket is finished i can see it in a list box name FinishedJobs, when i double click on a ticket inside the listbox it ask me if i want to reopen it or send it to print. The first one (reopen) is done but the second one i can't get it to work.
The problem is i have the ticket number in a variable named strCriteria and i want to use that value and put it in the criteria inside the query name JobsTicketGeneralReport, so i can open a report using that query. 
PLEASE HELP ME TO CHANGE THE CRITERIA IN THE QUERY TO SEARCH MY TICKET NUMBER. I'M WILLING TO CHANGE THE CODES IF YOU SUGGEST THAT.

NOTE: My query is a combine query it has 6 tables and has the ticket number in common, when i call the ticket number it bring the information of all tables.

This what i am doing:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim qdfOld As String
Dim strSQL As String
' Get the database and stored query
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("JobsticketGeneralReport")
' Loop through the selected items in the list box and build a text string
For Each varItem In Me!List0.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me.List0.Column(0) & "'"
Next varItem
' Check that user selected something
If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You did not select anything from the list" _
        , vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
    Exit Sub
End If
'Debug.Print strCriteria

' Remove the leading comma from the string
strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)
Debug.Print strCriteria

' change criteria in query
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Trim(strCriteria)
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

DoCmd.OpenQuery "JobsticketgeneralReport"
DoCmd.OpenReport "JobsticketgeneralReport", acpreview
rst.Close
qdf.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

HERE IS MY SQL:

```
SELECT JobsOrder.StartDigDate, JobsOrder.Ticket, JobsOrder.DigNumber, JobsOrder.JobType, 
       JobsOrder.JobAddressNumber, JobsOrder.JobAddressName, JobsOrder.JobAddressTown,
       JobsOrder.JobDescription, JobsOrder.AssetID, JobsOrder.Notes, JobsOrder.FINISH,
       JobsOrder.updateGIS, JobsOrder.Priority, GENERAL.STARTJOBDATE, GENERAL.ENDJOBDATE, 
       GENERAL.DAY1, GENERAL.DAY2, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE0, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE1, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE2, 
       GENERAL.EMPLOYEE3, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE4, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE5, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE6, 
       GENERAL.EMPLOYEE7, GENERAL.VEHICLE0, GENERAL.VEHICLE1, GENERAL.VEHICLE2, 
       GENERAL.VEHICLE3, GENERAL.VEHICLE4, GENERAL.VEHICLE5, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE0TIME, 
       GENERAL.EMPLOYEE1TIME, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE2TIME, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE3TIME, 
       GENERAL.EMPLOYEE4TIME, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE5TIME, GENERAL.EMPLOYEE6TIME, 
       GENERAL.EMPLOYEE7TIME, GENERAL.DRAWINGATT, GENERAL.FINISH, GENERAL.ASPHALT, 
       GENERAL.ROW, GENERAL.CONCRETE, GENERAL.DIRT, GENERAL.TRENCH, MAINS.[JOBTYPE-MAIN], 
       MAINS.MATERIAL, MAINS.SIZE, MAINS.DEPTH, MAINS.INTERNALCONDITION, MAINS.COMMENTS, 
       MAINS.REPAIRLOCATION, MAINS.LOCATION1, MAINS.LOCATION2, MAINS.MATERIAL1, 
       MAINS.MATERIAL2, MAINS.MATERIAL3, MAINS.MATERIAL4, MAINS.MATERIAL5, 
       MAINS.MATERIAL6, MAINS.MATERIAL7, MAINS.MATERIAL8, MAINS.MATERIAL9, 
       MAINS.MATERIAL10, MAINS.MATERIAL11, MAINS.MATERIAL12, MAINS.QTY1, MAINS.QTY2, 
       MAINS.QTY3, MAINS.QTY4, MAINS.QTY5, MAINS.QTY6, MAINS.QTY7, MAINS.QTY8, 
       MAINS.QTY9, MAINS.QTY10, MAINS.QTY11, MAINS.QTY12, MAINS.ENABLE, SERVICES.JOBPERFORMBY, 
       SERVICES.SERVICEASSET, SERVICES.OFFON, SERVICES.[MATERIAL-MC], SERVICES.[SIZE-MC], 
       SERVICES.[DEPTH-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL-CB], SERVICES.[SIZE-CB], SERVICES.[DEPTH-CB], 
       SERVICES.CURBBOXLOCATION, SERVICES.LOCATION1, SERVICES.LOCATION2, SERVICES.LOCATION3, 
       SERVICES.[SERVICE-COMMENT], SERVICES.[MATERIAL1-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL2-MC], 
       SERVICES.[MATERIAL3-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL4-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL5-MC], 
       SERVICES.[MATERIAL6-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL7-MC], SERVICES.[MATERIAL8-MC], 
       SERVICES.[QTY1-MC], SERVICES.[QTY2-MC], SERVICES.[QTY3-MC], SERVICES.[QTY4-MC], 
       SERVICES.[QTY5-MC], SERVICES.[QTY6-MC], SERVICES.[QTY7-MC], SERVICES.[QTY8-MC], 
       SERVICES.[MATERIAL1-CB], SERVICES.[MATERIAL2-CB], SERVICES.[MATERIAL3-CB], 
       SERVICES.[MATERIAL4-CB], SERVICES.[MATERIAL5-CB], SERVICES.[MATERIAL6-CB], 
       SERVICES.[MATERIAL7-CB], SERVICES.[MATERIAL8-CB], SERVICES.[QTY1-CB], 
       SERVICES.[QTY2-CB], SERVICES.[QTY3-CB], SERVICES.[QTY4-CB], SERVICES.[QTY5-CB], 
       SERVICES.[QTY6-CB], SERVICES.[QTY7-CB], SERVICES.[QTY8-CB], SERVICES.REPAIR, 
       SERVICES.Replace, SERVICES.INSTALL, SERVICES.REMOVE, SERVICES.TEMPDISCONNECT, 
       SERVICES.ENABLE, HYDRANT.[ENABLE-H], HYDRANT.[HYDRANT-ASSET], HYDRANT.[REPAIR-H], 
       HYDRANT.[REPLACE-H], HYDRANT.[INSTALL-H], HYDRANT.FLUSH, HYDRANT.FLOWTEST, 
       HYDRANT.PARTS1, HYDRANT.PARTS2, HYDRANT.PARTS3, HYDRANT.PARTS4, HYDRANT.PARTS5, 
       HYDRANT.PARTS6, HYDRANT.PARTS7, HYDRANT.PARTS8, HYDRANT.[QTY1-H], HYDRANT.[QTY2-H], 
       HYDRANT.[QTY3-H], HYDRANT.[QTY4-H], HYDRANT.[QTY5-H], HYDRANT.[QTY6-H], 
       HYDRANT.[QTY7-H], HYDRANT.[QTY8-H], HYDRANT.JOBPERFORM, HYDRANT.[MANUFACTORY OLD], 
       HYDRANT.MANUFACTORY, HYDRANT.SIZENEW, HYDRANT.SIZEOLD, HYDRANT.JOBNOTES, 
       HYDRANT.TIMEOPEND, HYDRANT.TIMECLOSED, HYDRANT.TIMETOCLEAR, HYDRANT.COLOROPEN, 
       HYDRANT.COLORCLOSE, HYDRANT.REMARKS, HYDRANT.[STATIC-PRESSURE], HYDRANT.[RESIDUAL-PRESSURE], 
       HYDRANT.[PITOT-TESTFLOWRATE], HYDRANT.CAPACITY, HYDRANT.[ASSET-ID1], 
       HYDRANT.[ASSET-ID2], VALVES.ENABLE, VALVES.[REPAIR-V], VALVES.[REPLACE-V], 
       VALVES.[INSTALL-V], VALVES.[REMOVE-V], VALVES.[MAINTENANCE-V], VALVES.VALVECOMMENT, 
       VALVES.[MATERIAL1-V], VALVES.[MATERIAL2-V], VALVES.[MATERIAL3-V], VALVES.[MATERIAL4-V], 
       VALVES.[MATERIAL5-V], VALVES.[MATERIAL6-V], VALVES.[QTY1-V], VALVES.[QTY2-V], 
       VALVES.[QTY3-V], VALVES.[QTY4-V], VALVES.[QTY5-V], VALVES.[QTY6-V], 
       VALVES.[LOCATION1-V], VALVES.[LOCATION2-V], VALVES.[LOCATION3-V], VALVES.[LOCATION4-V], 
       VALVES.VALVE1, VALVES.VALVE2, VALVES.VALVE3, VALVES.VALVE4, VALVES.VALVE5, 
       VALVES.VALVE6, VALVES.VALVE7, VALVES.VALVE8, VALVES.VALVEPOSITION1, 
       VALVES.VALVEPOSITION2, VALVES.VALVEPOSITION3, VALVES.VALVEPOSITION4, 
       VALVES.VALVEPOSITION5, VALVES.VALVEPOSITION6, VALVES.VALVEPOSITION7, 
       VALVES.VALVEPOSITION8, VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS1], VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS2], 
       VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS3], VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS4], VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS5], 
       VALVES.[VALVE- TURNS6], VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS7], VALVES.[VALVE-TURNS8], 
       VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH1], VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH2], VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH3], 
       VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH4], VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH5], VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH6], 
       VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH7], VALVES.[VALVE-DEPTH8], VALVES.REASON1, VALVES.REASON2, 
       VALVES.REASON3, VALVES.REASON4, VALVES.REASON5, VALVES.REASON6, VALVES.REASON7, 
       VALVES.REASON8, INSPECT.ENABLE, INSPECT.[CURBBOX-I], INSPECT.[VALVEBOX-I], 
       INSPECT.[SERVICE-I], INSPECT.CURBBOXREMARKS, INSPECT.VALVEBOXREMARKS, INSPECT.SERVICEREMARKS
FROM (((((JobsOrder 
INNER JOIN [GENERAL] ON JobsOrder.Ticket = GENERAL.TICKET) 
INNER JOIN MAINS ON GENERAL.TICKET = MAINS.TICKET) 
INNER JOIN SERVICES ON MAINS.TICKET = SERVICES.TICKET) 
INNER JOIN HYDRANT ON SERVICES.TICKET = HYDRANT.TICKET) 
INNER JOIN VALVES ON HYDRANT.TICKET = VALVES.TICKET) 
INNER JOIN INSPECT ON VALVES.TICKET = INSPECT.TICKET
WHERE (((JobsOrder.Ticket)=[ticket]) 
  AND ((JobsOrder.FINISH)=True))
ORDER BY JobsOrder.StartDigDate, JobsOrder.Ticket;
```

Comment: Can you post the query and where criteria should apply? In `where` clause? Also, do note: reports can filter using form controls like listboxes as long as form is opened.

Comment: i added a picture, just click in the first line where says :
"enter image description here"

Comment: i am receiving this error:  access error '3079' the specified field '[ticket]' could refer to more than one table listed in the from clause of you sql statement

Comment: Image doesn't help. Please post the query's SQL statement.

Comment: is big so here it is. i updated my question

Comment: What datatype is `JobsOrder.Ticket` ?

Comment: is a text and it belong to jobsorder table

Comment: This SQL desperately needs normalization with one-to-many table relationships. But to filter query/report by the listbox, again point where clause to form control: `WHERE ((JobsOrder.Ticket) = Forms!frmname!listboxname)` or use `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` on report open to same condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a parameter in the query, you should explicitly define it. Also, it is a good idea to give the parameter a different name than the involved tables and fields.

To do this, use the "Parameters" window in query design, or add a `PARAMETERS` clause to the beginning of the SQL:

```
PARAMETERS parTicket Text ( 255 );
SELECT .....
```

and in the WHERE clause

```
WHERE (((JobsOrder.Ticket)=[parTicket])
```

This is mainly useful if you want to read data from the query in VBA, i.e. you need this for

```
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

**But** if the query is RecordSource for a report, this won't work, because the report opens its own instance of the query. In this case, you need Parfait's solution: directly use the listbox in the query.

```
WHERE ((JobsOrder.Ticket) = Forms!yourForm!List0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each varItem In Me!List0.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me.List0.Column(0) & "'"
Next varItem
```

This cannot work - you must use `varItem` in the loop.

`Me.List0.Column(0)` will always pick the same element.

```
Debug.Print strCriteria
```

This should have told you what went wrong.

Comment: i know, i'm using this codes just to grab the ticket number, which it doing it alright, my problem is using the value of strCriteria in the query criteria to look for that ticket number. this is the line i have proble. qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Trim(strCriteria)

Comment: inside the query in the Ticket Criteria field i put [ticket] like a parameter, but when i run the query always ask me for the ticket, when i am using this line to give the value to it qdf.Parameters(0).Value = Trim(strCriteria)

Comment: Then why do you have a loop?? You could simply use `strCriteria = "'" & Me.List0.Column(0) & "'"` (and if it is a number, without the `'`)

Comment: that is for multiselection in the list box, but i just need a way to change the criteria in the query with the strCriteria value

Comment: @JOSELEON: If the listbox **is** multiselect, and your report is supposed to show multiple tickets, then your whole approach with parameters won't work. You will need to dynamically create a filter and apply it when opening the report.